# Why does my internet connection work even if my ipv4 is 169.x.y.z?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, ipv4

I'm still fairly new to network diagnostics and was snooping around when I saw comments about checking if your ipv4 was set at 169.x.y.z to know that the network issues revolved around the router not receiving the dhcp request. I was curious what my own was set at and turns out it was also 169.x.y.z, which confuses me because doesn't that mean i was never assigned an ip address from the router? If not, then how was I still connected to the internet? I could be confusing a lot of concepts here so a nice explanation can help point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS do you use, and what is in your routing table?

Comment: Without knowing any other details, my best guess is you have an IPv6 address but not an IPv4. But past that this question is way too broad and the answers provided are way too broad as well.

Answer (score 1):

A few different explanations:

1. There are lots of addresses that start with 169.x.y.z that are normal, publicly routable addresses that may have been allocated to your ISP and your ISP assigned to your device.
2. The block you're thinking of, that is set aside for IPv4 link-local addressing, is 169.254.x.y. So without knowing whether or not your second octet is 254, we can't say whether there's anything surprising about getting on the Internet with that address.
3. Even if you *do* have a 169.254.x.y IP address, it's conceivable that your router is acting as a NAT (NAPT) gateway for that subnet, and treating it like an RFC1918 private subnet. I've seen routers that try to guarantee connectivity for all clients by automatically doing NAT for whatever addresses any client happens to be using. Also, I suspect most home gateway routers are dumb enough to let you configure the 169.254.x.y subnet as your NAT private subnet.
4. Your computer could be getting onto the Internet via IPv6, likely via "NAT64", which is a scheme where your client only gets an IPv6 address, but when it needs to talk to an IPv4-only host, it does so by way of a "NAT64" NAT gateway, usually at the ISP. Most people don't realize this, but wireless carrier T-Mobile in the USA is "IPv6 only" in this way. If you have a smartphone on T-Mobile, it only gets an IPv6 address. When you need to reach an IPv4-only server, your phone talks to T-Mobile's NAT64 gateway which translates your IPv6-only packets into IPv4 packets before relaying them along to the IPv4-only server. I stress the likelihood of NAT64 because even in 2018, not enough services are reachable via IPv6, so if you were only able to reach IPv6-capable servers, your web browsing experience would still be pretty weird and broken.

Comment: The problem with this answer is the question is too vague to provide an answer. So while you might have good intentions with this answer, the reality visit’s just a fairly random list of educated ideas; not an answer. This question needs to be clarified or closed.

Comment: Yeah you're right, my ipv4 does not have .254 in the second set of digits. Your answer was helpful and a good read. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`169.254.0.0/16` is a block that is [reserved for "*Link-Local Addresses*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4) - i.e: `169.254.0.0` to `169.254.255.255`. Windows is quite aggressive at falling back to a link-local address, and will do this automatically if it can't get an address from [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), or if it fails to renew a DHCP lease.

A typical home network router will allocate IP addresses via DHCP using the `192.168.0.0/16` block, reserved for "*Private Network*" use - i.e: `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255`. The block is most commonly broken into either `192.168.0.x/24` or `192.168.1.x/24` by default settings.

I would be *very* surprised if your computer actually had internet access with *only* this address, as a link-local address won't have any [routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) (default gateway) or [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) servers available... Unless you're using this range by explicitly configuring your router accordingly - something which technically you shouldn't do.

It's possible that you had two addresses assigned, the link-local address (left over from a failed DHCP interaction), and an address from your DHCP server (which would provide a gateway and DNS servers).

Comment: The problem with this answer is the question is too vague to provide an answer. So while you might have good intentions with this answer, the reality visit’s just a fairly random list of educated ideas; not an answer. This question needs to be clarified or closed.